# Correct way to update data in service then notifydatasetchanged in activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-service, notifydatasetchanged

Im facing this scenario where in my chat app i maintain the conversations in service and when a new message is added to it, i need to update the listview, that is inside a fragment in activity.
I've tried to update the conversation, then send a broadcast that is received in fragment and it seemed to work but after a while I realized that sometimes i get a crash with a IllegalStateException.
I think this is a trivial situation then there must be a standard/common way to handle this.
Note: im using Otto in my app, if i try to notify the UI through it, could it work?
**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a chat, you might hold some history in a case to show to user previous/received messages. Here is from top of mind ways to do it:

1. Use DB. DB to store all messages and etc. Service update DB, sends local broadcast, Loader receives broadcast and trigger onContentChanged, loader loads data from DB, UI (fragment, activity and etc.) receives new data from loader.
2. Use singleton manager to hold (in runtime only of course) messages. Once receive, service tell manager to add new message(s). UI has subscribed to manager to listen to changes. Manager notifies subscribers about new messages.

I am sure there are other scenarios and solutions, depends on what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: This conversations are so non persistent data. I think these solutions are good but my app is not prepared to it. I could not be done with more simple solution?